# VS Code unable to format C# file using .editorconfig, `Format Document` doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp, editorconfig

I have a C# project with VS Code, having `ms-dotnettools.csharp` and `editorconfig.editorconfig` extensions (among others). As per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846128/editorconfig-for-vs-code-not-working) I installed `npm install -g editorconfig`.

My .editorconfig file is as follow:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

[*.cs]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 3
```

As you can see in the image, editor show 3 spaces, but `Format Document` does nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I was able to make it work:

- Remove `"editor.defaultFormatter"`, `"editor.insertSpaces"` and other related to styling.
- Restart OmniSharp each time I make change to .editorconfig.
- Use official configs from [official source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options).

My `editorconfig` is now:

```
root = true

[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true

[*.cs]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
csharp_new_line_before_else = true
csharp_new_line_before_catch = true
csharp_new_line_before_finally = true
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = false
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = false
csharp_new_line_between_query_expression_clauses = false
```